# Intel Display adapters taking HUGE chunks of space in my driver store, on SSD

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, intel-graphics, display-driver

Intel is killing my SSD with all this space usage, My HDD is full because of this.

Now I'm wondering of some of these can be deleted as there's no way that all these drivers are needed. They all seem to be the same version however, so none can be flagged as obsolete. Anyone has any idea if some of them can be cleared?

I have the PE70 6QD which has an integrated Intel HD display card and a Geforce GTX950M, that explains why there are both Intel and NVIDIA drivers in the list. The Intel card is used for low power general purpose and the NVIDIA card is used for high graphics demands like Video editing and 3D processing.

[image]

Comment: Try it. Worst case.  You reinstall them

Comment: I've read about deleting things in your driver store being very bad and potentially creating unrecoverable problems, even with a driver reinstall... Not sure I'm comfortable randomly deleting drivers

Comment: So uninstall the Intel drivers from the Control Panel, this will allow you to only remove the drivers, that are not actually in use.  Without reading what you have read, I couldn't comment, on the accuracy of whatever you read.  You have a Nvidia device driver installed, it's unlikely, the Intel device is even being used.  I, however, know nothing about your configuration, so I can't comment with regard to that.

Comment: I've added some details in my question, and in Control Panel, there is only a 3.63MB Intel graphics driver so there's obviously a problem hahaha!

Comment: Control Panel doesn’t report the size of many applications correctly that’s been the case for 2 decades